# SwiftUI button path problem: unrecognized selector error pops up when ran

Tags: ios, swift

Thread 1: Exception: "-[UniversityFinder.ViewController ButtonTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa924f04f00"

I'm using a storyboard to create a university finder and I needed a path for my button that leads to another page. I created a segue with the present modally mode. But when I run the Xcode, the error above pops up in the AppDelegate.swift page. Any advice to fix this error? Much appreciated.

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: At some time in the past you must have had a `ButtonTapped` function and connected your button to it.  You need to disconnect your button from `ButtonTapped` by ctrl-clicking on the button in the storyboard and then clicking on the (x) next to the `ButtonTapped` connection.

Answer (score 2):

You can try check storyboard or xib with this button outlet, delete all and reconnect outlet with function "ButtonTapped".